# How can I create a new window from within QML?

Tags: window, qml, qobject

Is there a way to create a completely new window instance, as a child window of the main QML window in a QmlApplication?

```
// ChildWindow.qml
Rectangle {
    id: childWindow
    width: 100
    height: 100
    // stuff
}

// main.qml
Rectangle {
    id: window
    width: 1000
    height: 600

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: createAWindow(childWindow);
    }
}
```

I am trying to avoid writing a `Q_OBJECT` class just for instanciating the new window within a new `QmlApplicationViewer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to create top-level windows using only built-in QML functionality.

However there's a project on Qt Labs called [Desktop Components](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/03/10/qml-components-for-desktop/), which among other things contains a [Window component](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/08/26/toplevel-windows-and-menus-with-qt-quick/), which allows you to create new top-level windows.

Comment: That looks awesome, thank you. My next step would have been to search for these Desktop Components, since I need them anyways. Didn't think they would do new windows, too ;)

Answer (score 48):

You can do it by using Qt.createComponent. Example (using Qt 5.3):

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    width: 200; height: 200
    visible: true

    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: qsTr("Click me")

        onClicked: {
            var component = Qt.createComponent("Child.qml")
            var window    = component.createObject(root)
            window.show()
        }
    }
}
```

**Child.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    width: 100; height: 100

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: qsTr("Hello World.")
    }
}
```

Comment: Inside main i am getting this error "qrc:///main.qml:59: ReferenceError: root is not defined", when i press click me button ?

Comment: It runs as expected here when I try it with qmlscene main.qml.

Comment: I am using QT 5.3.1 and i have QtQuick 2.2, QtQuick.Controls 1.1 instaed urs 2.3 and 1.2. Is this an issue ?

Comment: @User: "root is not defined" sounds like you forgot to ad the `id: root` to the `ApplicationWindow` in the **main.qml**-file... Also why not try importing the newer *QtQuick.Controls*? Most likely this will not break anything but improve small things...

Comment: The Error "root not defined" is because its unquoted. this way should work: `var window    = component.createObject("root")`

Comment: @MohammadKanan that is absolutely wrong. Please read the documentation on frameworks you use rather than guessing what might be required.
The parameter passed to createObject is [the parent of the created component](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#createObject-method). You can omit that but then you have to keep a reference to the object or it will be destroyed. Passing a string there doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @StefanFabian, I didnt state anything opposing the parent relationship .. , honestly I totally forgot the details that made me put this commit. That said, quoting still works with or without the `id = root` on top parent ...  it _might NOT however be correct as to set that specific 'root' parent_ to the created object .. I would agree to that ..

Comment: No, you stated that the ID should be quoted and that is [incorrect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html#creating-a-component-dynamically). The method expects a QtObject as parameter and AFAIK a string is not a QtObject. Hence, this is undefined behavior. I assume it works because it ignores your invalid parameter and just assumes no parent but I haven't looked at the relevant code so that's just a guess.