# Create new window using QML

Tags: qt, window, qml

```
  MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                         acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton
                         onEntered: Function.call(somefunc())
                         onExited: console.log("Mouse Exited");
                onClicked: {
                    Qt.quit();
                }
            }
```

How to create a new window using the function somefunc() when my mouse enters the  Mouse Area. Is it possible? 
I cannot find any way to integrate a C++ file into Qt so that I can use the function to create a new window.

Comment: What about http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/30689 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to achieve what you want. C++ and QML can work together in some ways but none of them (as far as I know) involves embedding the C++ code into the QML code.
Before going forward I recommend you to ask yourself the following:

1. Why not defining the window itself in QML?
2. Why not defining `somefunc()` in JavaScript, a language you can use in your QML file.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible create a new window even from Qml or C++, but in Qml is most easy, you can declare Component element containing a element of qml (how show a pop up but the functionality how window is very limited) or create a Window element, read this:

[How can I create a new window from within QML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327894/how-can-i-create-a-new-window-from-within-qml)

And this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdeclarativedynamicobjects.html, maybe this can help.