# How can I open second qml page on button click

Tags: qt, qml

I use Qt 5.5.0 and Qt Creator 3.4.2 on Mac-book, I want to open second qml on button click, I want to develop application in which login page come and after login control move to next page.

I try suggestion of stack**overflow**, but still I face problem to open next qml on button click.

I tried

```
button2.onClicked:{
                        var component = Qt.createComponent("test.qml")
                        var window    = component.createObject(root)
                        window.show()
        }
```

[How can I create a new window from within QML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327894/how-can-i-create-a-new-window-from-within-qml)

In upper case error come related to root, ReferenceError: root is not defined. I gave root id in test.qml file.

I also tried many more example to solve to develop functionality. Please give brief idea or code to develop this functionality.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below works, Take note of the property `status` and the function `errorString()` – they will give you information in debugging (.e.g. "file not found" errors, components not ready, etc).

See these pages for background:
 
[Dynamic QML Object Creation from JavaScript](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html)
[Component QML Type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#status-prop)
[Window QML Type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#details)

```
   function createWindows() {
     var component = Qt.createComponent("Child.qml");
     console.log("Component Status:", component.status, component.errorString());
     var window = component.createObject(root, {"x": 100, "y": 300});
     window.show();
    }
```

Comment: I have just started learning QT.  Can you help to understand what is `root` in your above code snippet  ?

Comment: @Vikrant – see the `Component` documentation for `createObject` http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#createObject-method – "root" is just a variable name for an optional parent object

Answer (score 0):

For this type of ui I'd use `[StackView][1]` component that allows also animations between transitions. Other solution is to use a Loader component.